# Why image distorted by UV Map node is like lowres on output?

Tags: uv, node-editor, compositing-nodes

*Image* texture looks pixelated (like a low-res) on output in the *UV Map* node when using the Compositor editor even source is high-res.

Distortion of image is from UV render pass. Did I miss something in setup?

[image: Example-screenshot]

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise Huh? The OP here sounds like they *don't* want pixelation..

Comment: Not knowing the texture size, I would suspect that the exact same issue is being encountered.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise I think gandalf3 is right, he seems to be asking why it is pixelated, not how to make it pixelated.  Even if that answer applies to this question (and I don't see how it does) [the question isn't a duplicate](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/567/5705).  I might suggest a close for being unclear though.

Comment: I did not realize that my voting to close *as unclear what you are asking* would count as a close vote for a duplicate.  Is this a bug or is that just how it works?  I don't think the question is a duplicate at all.

Comment: @PGmath Good point. And I have no idea why it would close as a duplicate when you did not vote that way . . .

Comment: @PGmath That's how it works. I don't really like it either, but I think it does this because it gives the close reason provided by the majority of close voters and a list of the close voters (regardless of close reason). BTW, I don't really see what's unclear about the question? I tried and failed to find an answer (never used the UV pass before), but perhaps I'm missing something..

Comment: @vklidu Try saving the UV pass as full floating point exr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by @gandalf3 in a comment ... the UV pass has to be saved as full floating point EXR file format to have enough color range to translate texture without pixelation.